# UnreachableBrowserException in PhantomJS

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using Selenium Webdriver and PhantomJS version 2.0.0

I'm getting "org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died." error when I execute my code.

Below is a sample code of my class.

```
rateMaintenancePg   =   createRatePg.closeGuideRatesUI();
Sleep(6);
getscreenshot();
Sleep(6);
System.out.println("Closed Create Rate UI.");
Sleep(3);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("main");
driver.switchTo().frame("frmTabmenu_spnTabMenus_0");
Sleep(3);
System.out.println("Go to iframe frmTabmenu_spnTabMenus_0");
homePg  =   rateMaintenancePg.closeRateMaintenanceUI();
Sleep(3);
getscreenshot();
Sleep(3);
driver.navigate().refresh();
Sleep(4);
```

I'm getting this error in this line:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Run the following command, kill all running IEDriverServer.exe processes (if any)

Comment: I tried that way. But still that error is there. This works fine in Firefox driver.

Comment: What preceded the above? Is it possible that the driver failed on a preceding step? Just prior to the defaultContext() statement what happens when you insert System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); ?

Comment: Yes I added the statement "System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());" prior to the defaultContent() and my console prints this information. Mar 10, 2016 2:18:12 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:26956: Connection reset
Mar 10, 2016 2:18:12 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:26956

Comment: Also this information is in my log file several times. [INFO  - 2016-03-10T05:13:21.702Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you open more than one PhantomJs driver objects. 
The solution is you have to kill all the running PhantomJs drivers in your machine before start the test suite.